# Ranking system for a cooperative game

Tags: scoring-algorithm

A cooperative game in which two players share a final score on each match.

I would like to have an individual ranking for each player in the system considering all matches between all players ever played.

A typical score varies from `500` to `7000` (in theory, from `0` to `10000+`).

My first thought is to use the score as the ranking itself as follows:

- `Player-A` with `NA` matches (ever played) and ranking `RA` plays with `Player-B` with `NB` matches and ranking `RB`.
- The expected score is `(RA+RB)/2` (this is an assumption that is probably close to reality, but I don't have enough data).
- The actual score was `RX`, which is distant `D = RX-(RA+RB)/2` from the expectation.
- The new ranking for `Player-A` is `RA+D/NA` and `NA` is incremented.
- The new ranking for `Player-B` is `RB+D/NB` and `NB` is incremented.
- A new player enters the system with `1` match and ranking `0`.

My specific questions:

- Is there an existing ranking system designed for games like this?
- If my assumption is correct, is the proposed system good?
- If my assumption is *not* entirely correct, what should be changed? It is guaranteed, at least, that `RX` is between `RA` and `RB`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Elo Rating system.  It’s what is used for chess and a variant of it is used for CSGO.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system

Comment: AFAIK Elo is not designed for cooperative games and does not take into account points (only win/loss). How could it be adapted?

Comment: Actually you might want to look in to TrueSkill 2.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2018/03/trueskill2.pdf

Comment: I don't see how TrueSkill 2 could be adapted. It also seems to be unnecessarily complex to this game.